# Unable to initialize ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to do in a rails console

```
>> user = User.new(:name => "", :email => "test@example.com")
=> #<User not initialized>
```

My User class looks like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :email
  has_many :microposts

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @name  = attributes[:name]
    @email = attributes[:email]
  end 

  def formatted_email
    "#{@name} <#{@email}>"
  end
end
```

I am following along from the [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=4.0#sec-presence_validation). Why am I not able to initialize the object ?

Comment: according to your tutorial, they ask you to use `name: "", email: ""` not `:name => "", :email => ""` could this be your problem?

Comment: I thought that could be the problem. But i've tried both style with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Copy exactly from the book and you should be fine. (*Note*: I am the author.)

The example in question is from [Chapter 4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#top) of the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and is *not* an Active Record model. In particular, the User class shown in the question is based on [Listing 4.9](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code-example_user):

```js
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @name  = attributes[:name]
    @email = attributes[:email]
  end

  def formatted_email
    "#{@name} <#{@email}>"
  end
end
```

This class does *not* inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, but rather must be included explicitly in the console using `require './example_user.rb'`, as described in [Section 4.4.5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#sec-a_user_class). The behavior you're seeing is the result of including `< ActiveRecord::Base` in the first line, but if you copy the code in [Listing 4.9](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code-example_user) exactly you should see the expected behavior.

Comment: mhartl, thanks for answering. I am actually looking at Ch 6 and not Ch 4. And Listing 6.2 says User < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: The code you're using is a confused combination of the User class from Chapter 4 and ActiveRecord::Base from Chapter 6. Nowhere in the book is ActiveRecord::Base ever combined with "def initialize", "def formatted_email", etc. In other words, the tl;dr still applies: copy exactly from the book and you should be fine.

Comment: you were right. The problem was, I had the field info duplicated in both the model class and the Migration class. Serves me right for not keeping things dry. Almost lost faith in rails!!

Answer (score 2):

are  you  running your console in the same file directory  as your  project?  I'd also try switching up the  notation to the example used in the book and  see if that gets you anywhere.

you can also try calling User.new with no attributes and see if it generates an object as listed in 6.1.3  of the tutorial  ,  and then fill in the attributes  and  see if it works.

also make sure you dont have a  validation on your user name in your model.

and a last check you can run user.error  to see why it might not be saving

Answer (score 2):

First, I assume that `User` model persists in your Rails app. That means, that you already have a **migrated `User`** model before running `rails console`.
If that table doesn't exist, you will be instanly prompted with:

> => User(Table doesn't exist)

Now, let's have some fun in `rails console`:
First things first, don't override `initialize` method in Rails model; While creating an object initialize method from ActiveRecord takes precedence (I think), so it may create conflicts. Instead use `after_initialize` callback. In console:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  def after_initialize(attributes = {})
    self[:name]  = attributes[:name]
    self[:email] = attributes[:email]
  end
  def formatted_email
    "#{self.name} <#{self.email}>"
  end
end
```

Now,

```
u = User.new({name: "Foo", email: "foo@bar.org"})
#<User name: "Foo", email: "foo@bar.org", created_at:nil updated_at: nil>
u.formatted_email
#=> "Foo <foo@bar.org>"
```

All done! Sweet.

**UPDATE**:
As per your recent [gist](https://gist.github.com/gprasant/e9d454bc0246dbba1e18); I see no point of having `after_initialize` at all. Rails does that on it's own.
First thing first, replace `attr_accessor` with `attr_accessbile`.
`attr_accessor` is ruby method(courtesy, metaprogramming) which creates getter and setter for provided instance variable. Rails uses `attr_accessible` for that; for security concerns, only instance variables allowed in `attr_accessible` allowed for mass-assignment (by sending params hash).

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  #def after_initialize(attributes = {})
  #  self[:name]  = attributes[:name]
  #  self[:email] = attributes[:email]
  #end 

  def formatted_email
    "#{self.name} <#{self.email}>"
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions. No luck so far :-(
Heres a gist https://gist.github.com/gprasant/e9d454bc0246dbba1e18

Comment: as per your gist, I modified the answer above. It will certainly help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running console using the `rails c` command to load your environment from the root directory of your project? Typing `irb` to start a console session does not load the Rails application environment by itself.

Here are some more troubleshooting tips

- Check to make sure that the development database specified in `config/database.yml` is running
- Check to make sure a migration exists to create the Users table
- Check to make sure the migrations have run with `rake db:migrate`
- Check to make sure that a Users table actually does exist in the database, with columns of type `varchar` (or `text`) for fields :name and :email

Comment: Tried all your trouble-shooting tips. Still no result. Its quite a 3 pipe problem